# How to alert in an iframe without put codes outside of the iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried this code: `document.getElementById('targetFrame').contentWindow.targetFunction();`
from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139953/displaying-an-alert-box-inside-an-iframe-in-an-html-page#:%7E:text=What%20you%20will%20want%20to,(using%20targetFunction%20as%20example).) but it seems like you have to put it outside of the iframe. How can you do it only in the iframe and not anything outside of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

The only way a code in a frame can communicate with parent page and vice versa, is via [postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)